# Property does not exist on state - Using React Router Hooks with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I having some problems when using react-router-dom hooks + TypeScript.

Trying to access some state property would give an error saying that it doesn't exist

Refer to:

[image]

One of the workarounds that I had to do in order to continue development, was to cast it to `any`

```
 const location = useLocation() as any;
```

How can I pass a valid interface to the useLocation generic in order to access state properties without warnings?

```
  useDidMount(() => {
    if (location.state?.newTransactions) {
      scroll.scrollToBottom();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`useLocation` accepts a generic parameter that determines the type of the `state` property, so:

```
const location = useLocation<YourStateTypeHere>();
```

For instance:

```
interface LocationState {
    newTransactions?: boolean;
}

// ...
const location = useLocation<LocationState>();

// ...
useDidMount(() => {
    if (location.state?.newTransactions) {
        scroll.scrollToBottom();
    }
});
```

---

How I got there (since I hadn't used that before), in case it's useful: I know that the TypeScript bindings for most hooks implement at least one generic parameter, so when I saw that React Router's [`location`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/location) incorporated programmer-defined state, I figured it probably accepted one. So I opened a project where I'm using React Router and TypeScript, and hovered over a `useLocation` in the code. Sure enough, the popup showed a generic parameter, which got applied to the `state` property. Result!

Answer (score 1):

Didn't works for router V6

this is the declaration

```js
export declare function useLocation(): Location;
```

This doesn't take any argument type

According to [github issue](https://github.com/reach/router/issues/414#issuecomment-859406190) someone suggested

```js
interface CustomizedState {
  myState: string
}

const location = useLocation();
const state = location.state as CustomizedState; // Type Casting, then you can get the params passed via router
const { myState } = state;
```